# What is the difference between circuit satisfiability and q-sat?

Tags: algorithm

Also, why is QSat PSPACE-Complete and Circuit Satisfiability NP-Complete? Aren't they the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSAT is the problem relating to TQBF (true quantity Boolean formulae). These formula have their variables bound at the very beginning. If the formula evaluated to true or false then the formula is a in the language of TQBF. If it is PSPACE-complete then the language resides in PSPACE and it is also PSPACE-hard. Using a recursive algorithm to determine the evaluation of the formula (depending if it has quantifiers or not) will tell you if those statements are true. By showing it is PSPACE-hard you show that the language must be reducible to TQBF in polynomial time.

The CSAT problem is the problem regarding the decision problem of determining if a Boolean circuit has a set of inputs that evaluate, in terms of the output, to true. It is proven to be NP-complete as it is in NP space and is reducible in polynomial time.

QSAT evaluation of its space classing and also its reduction time is determined without regard to the state of the output (true or false), solving the recursive algorithm is determined by whether the formula has no quantifiers (thus returning the formula) or checking both possible values for the first variable (if it has quantifiers). This evaluation is for the amount of memory space required to solve it, specifically logarithmic space. CSAT is evaluated based on the output state (true being the solvable one in this case) and as such is determined not by spacial requirement but by total reduction time. Specifically containing n arbitrary gates, it can be decided in O(2^0.4058n).